# how to add css animation on div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, show-hide

I am trying to do a  show/hide animation. 1st div will show and 2nd div hide for first time then when i will "details" button which is in 1st div then show 2nd and same when i click "close" button which is in 2nd div then show 1st div and hide 2nd div. i did that no problem but i want to add some css effect when it will show and hide exmple like http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/index7.html there have many cool effect all are base on rollover effect i want to this on my click.. can you guess help me how to do..

Basic example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5e76

```
$("#details").click(function () {
    $(".one").hide();
    $(".two").show();
});

$("#close").click(function () {
    $(".two").hide();
    $(".one").show();
});
```

Comment: CSS doesn't do clicks. You'll need to use JavaScript or a server-side solution. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events

Comment: try looking into slideToggle or .animate({ width : 'toggle' }) with jquery/javascript

Comment: Also, please don't bypass SO policy with code tags.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.show();` and `.hide();` you could use `.fadeIn(n)` and `.fadeOut();`

where `n` is the number of miliseconds it will take.

e.g.

```
$('.one').fadeOut(500); // half a second.
```

PS: if these are unique, you should give them ID's to prevent an interaction being executed on multiple elements.

Also it will help yourself if you give your elements proper names.

e.g. `id="detail-box"` for instance.